# Save Response Data from Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code in a "new" jobs view:

```
<input type="text" id="address" style="width: 500px;"></input>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], {});

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place.address_components);
  });
</script>
```

What should my `create` action look like to save the resulting address fields when selecting an address from the autocomplete input field? I suppose I must find a way to populate my other form fields with the response. Also, any idea why the `postal_code` is not being shown in the results (but country is)?

My form view looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
  <% if @job.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @job.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :customer %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :customer %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :state %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :postal_code %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :postal_code %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this page answers my question:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

From there, I can submit the filled-out form using a basic `create` action.